# How do I create Python eggs from distutils source packages?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I vaguely remember some sort of setuptools wrapper that would generate .egg files from distutils source. Can someone jog my memory?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

setuptools monkey-patches some parts of distutils when it is imported.  When you use easy_install to get a distutils-based project from PyPI, it will create an egg (pip may do that too).  To do the same thing locally (i.e. in a directory that’s a code checkout or an unpacked tarball), use this trick: `python -c "import setuptools; execfile('setup.py')" bdist_egg`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Hopefully I won't have this hard a time finding it the next time I need it. Thanks.

Comment: In Python 3, `execfile` disappeared, so you'll want something like `python -c "import setuptools; exec(open('setup.py').read())" bdist_egg`.

Answer (score 23):

Have you tried

```
python setup.py bdist_egg
```

Here I assume you are using setuptools instead of distutils i.e.

in setup.py instead of

```
from distutils.core import setup
```

use

```
from setuptools import setup
```

Comment: Thanks, but looking for something that would turn someone else's distutils package into an egg. It does exist, as I found it before.

Comment: how I could build egg with "distutils" ?