# Python ingresdbi: Install under different directory

Tags: python, packaging, ingres

I would like to install the ingresdbi python package (http://code.ingres.com/ingres/drivers/python/main/) under a project I am creating. So I would like to specify the directory of my choice (inside the python project hierarchy) instead of the default one. Is this achievable? In addition, is there a way to create an .egg or something to distribute the package along with my python project, so that someone would not need to have installed it to their system?

Comment: python setup.py install --prefix=/some/path ?  python setup.py bdist_egg ? (from memory).  Or is this particular module unusual in some respect?

Comment: Actually, I can't do the things you have proposed Croad. For both I get:
`usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands`

Comment: Yes, I didn't look it up or test it, hence question marks.  Google / read docs and you should find it though: the actual commands are similar to what I wrote, and I have used them in the past.  I guess it's setup.py build bdist_egg (again, I didn't check the detail)?  With install possibly you may need to use both install and build commands to access needed options?  Don't remember for sure.

Answer (score 0):

From [How do I create Python eggs from distutils source packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950362/how-do-i-create-python-eggs-from-distutils-source-packages) you could try

```
python -c "import setuptools; execfile('setup.py')" bdist_egg
```

or checkout https://github.com/grantc/python-ingresdbi/tree/egg which gives you the option to use `bdist_egg`.

As for the installation prefix - I'd have to take a look. I no longer have a working Ingres installation and I'm not sure when I'd be able to look in to this.